# I am trying to add/remove a line-through on one ITEM only, angular

Tags: angular

**I am trying to add/remove a line-through on one ITEM only, on my todo list app, but the line-through mark all the list not only the item I clicked.**

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" />
<input type="submit" (click)="addItem()" value="Add" />
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of items; index as i">
    <tr
      (click)="test1()"
      [ngClass]="{ line: toggle === true, unline: toggle === false }"
    >
      {{item.name}}
    </tr>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS** for ngClass to add/remove line-through

```
.line
{
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
.unline
{
  text-decoration: null;
}
```

**tryit.component.ts**

```
export class TryitComponent implements OnInit {
  public name = '';
  public items: any[] = [];
  public toggle: boolean;

  constructor() {}

  public add(TodoItem: string): void {
    this.items.push({
      name: TodoItem,
    });
  }
  addItem(): void {
    this.add(this.name);
    this.name = '';
  }

  public test1() {
    this.toggle = !this.toggle;

    console.log(this.toggle);
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

Comment: Check my edited answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: You're not tracking which items should be marked as done

in your `add` method you should add a property to indicate what tasks are done and then edit your test method to toggle each task like so

```
export class TryitComponent implements OnInit {
  name = '';
  items: any[] = [];
  toggle: boolean;

  constructor() {}

  add(TodoItem: string): void {
    this.items.push({
      name: TodoItem,
      done: false,
    });
  }
  addItem(): void {
    this.add(this.name);
    this.name = '';
  }

  test1(index) {
    this.items[index].done = !this.items[index].done;
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

and use like this

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items; index as i">
        <tr (click)="test1(i)" [ngClass]=" item.done ? 'line' :  'unline'">
            {{item.name}}
        </tr>
    </li>
```

you can see the result here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-j3bbce?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: I went add the line on one item of the list, but when i click on the specific item all the list get a line
output ex:
 test 1
test 2
test 3 


problem when click on task the other tasks get line too

Comment: @MuhammadQandil that's because you're not tracking what items should be marked. I'll edit my answer to provide more context.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are using the same toggle flag for all

tags. It shoud be item-specific. Try like this

**HTML**

```
    <ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of items; index as i">
    <tr
      (click)="test1(item)"
      [ngClass]="item.toggle ? 'line' : 'unline'"
    >
      {{item.name}}
    </tr>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**tryit.component.ts**

```
 public test1(item) {
    item.toggle ? false : true
  }
```